# Html Css slide to left with linear motion

Tags: html, css

Hi I want to slide a div to left with some linear transition.

But no transition is happening. What am I doing wrong?

```js
 $("#EnvironmentSelect").addClass("animateToLeft");
```

```css
#EnvironmentSelect{
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transition: all 10s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 10s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 10s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 10s ease-in;
    transition: all 10s ease-in;
    }
    .animateToLeft {
    left: 60px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="EnvironmentSelect">
            <p class="Text">Lorem Ipsum:</p>
            <div>
                <p class="schoolEnvLabel EnvLabel">
                    <img src="~/Content/Images/1.png" />
                    1
                </p>
                <p class="homeEnvLabel EnvLabel">
                    <img src="~/Content/Images/2.png" />
                    2
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use css `animation`.

```css
#EnvironmentSelect {
  position: absolute;
  left:60px;
  animation:slide 5s;
}

@keyframes slide{
  0%{left:0;}
  100%{left:60px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="EnvironmentSelect">
  <p class="Text">Lorem Ipsum:</p>
  <div>
    <p class="schoolEnvLabel EnvLabel">
      <img src="~/Content/Images/1.png" /> 1
    </p>
    <p class="homeEnvLabel EnvLabel">
      <img src="~/Content/Images/2.png" /> 2
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: He is asking how to correct his current code, not for a completely different method of solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try using below css code or link.

[JsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/b91n23Lz/105/)

CSS Code-

```
#EnvironmentSelect {
  position: absolute;
}

.animateToLeft {
  left:60px;
  transform: translateX(-60px);
  -webkit-transition: all 10s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 10s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 10s ease;
  -o-transition: all 10s ease;
  transition: all 10s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add "left:0" to your base object's CSS.

This way the CSS will know where to animate the origin from.

Answer (score -1):

You should add

```
#EnvironmentSelect { left: 0 }
```

Also you should use more strong selector to rewrite first one:

```
#EnvironmentSelect.animateToLeft { left: 60px }
```

Also use "liner" for transition mode if you want linear transition

Final css should look like this

```css
#EnvironmentSelect {
left: 0;
position:absolute;
-webkit-transition: all 10s linear;
-moz-transition: all 10s linear;
-ms-transition: all 10s linear;
-o-transition: all 10s linear;
transition: all 10s linear;
}
#EnvironmentSelect.animateToLeft {
left: 60px;
}
```